# Laravel 8 whereJsonContains()

Tags: mysql, laravel

good day everyone. I cannot use the json_contains construct because my MySQL version does not support it. Is there an alternative build? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
->when(count($data) > 0, function ($query) use ($data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $filter) {
                $filter = is_string($filter) ? '\"' . $filter : $filter;
                $query->where('content', 'like', '%\"' . $key . '\":' . $filter . '%');
            }
            return $query;
        })
```

This is how I solved the problem.